# CKEditor failing in NSBasic IDE

Tags: ckeditor, nsbasic

I have followed the directions and done
1. Added the ckeditor.js file into the IDE.
2. Added a textArea named editor
3. Added code CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

When I run locally I am getting the following error:

ckeditor.js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c[a].dir=c.rtl[a]?"rtl":"ltr"').
line 248 column 50

On a server I get

ckeditor.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined.
line 248 column 54

Any ideas on this?

Live sample http://toolfolks.com/Project1/

Comment: line 258 50 is {c[a].dir=c.rtl[a]?"rtl":"ltr";b(a,c[a])};this[a]?d():CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl("lang/"+a+".js"),d,this)},detect:function(a,d){var b=this.languages;d=d||navigator.userLanguage||navigator.language||a;var c=d.toLowerCase().match(/([a-z]+)(?:-([a-z]+))?/),e=c[1],c=c[2];b[e+"-"+c]?e=e+"-"+c:b[e]||(e=null);CKEDITOR.lang.detect=e?function(){return e}

Answer (score 0):

It worked using this

Instead of dragging into the IDE.

So theres something amiss somewhere.